# Some problems about ShellExecute function

Tags: winapi, mfc, shellexecute

I want to invoke a command like this:

[image]

I am using this code:

```
 std::string szArg = " -i " + m_strSign;
 wstringstream wss;
 wss<<szArg.c_str();
 wstringstream wssa;
 wssa<<strToolupdater.c_str();
 ShellExecute(NULL,TEXT("open"), wssa.str().c_str(), wss.str().c_str(),TEXT(""),SW_NORMAL);
 wcout<<wssa.str().c_str()<<wss.str().c_str()<<endl;
```

The expected result is to execute `ToolUpdater.exe -i Hackeroid_Qqhcs`, but the actual result is executing `ToolUpdater.exe`, the input parameter is invalid.

Comment: And what is the expected result ? BTW don't post pictures of code but post the code.

Comment: the expected result is ToolUpdater.exe -i Hackeroid_Qqhcs,actually the real result  is ToolUpdater.exe.  the parameter is invalid.

Comment: Update your question please, as it stands here it is totally unclear.

Comment: Please read this: [MCVE].

Comment: There are several issues with your code. The most important one, there is no error handling for your call to [ShellExecute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153.aspx). None of the error codes this API reports resembles *"the parameter is invalid"*. Where did you get that from? This is not to say, that your parameters aren't wrong. They are. `wstringstream::str()` returns a temporary. Once you called `c_str()` on it, it's dead. You are passing pointers to dead beef into `ShellExecute` (and you should be using `ShellExecuteEx` anyway, if just for error reporting).

Comment: Your naming of variables leaves a lot to be desired. One might naively imagine that the difference between `wss` and `wssa` is that the latter contains the *arguments*, but apparently that is not the case. A *very* unclear question, made 10,000 times worse by the fact that you posted pictures of code instead of actual code.

Comment: @IInspectable: temp variables are not destroyed until the complete statement is finished.  Using `str().c_str()` directly in the `ShelExecute()` parameters is perfectly safe in this example.

Comment: Why is this tagged as MFC?  There isn't one piece of MFC in it. I think it is weird mixing your std::string and std::wstring and std::wstrstream objects.  Looks like all your doing is appending strings.  I'd just use a CString and append what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are mixing `std::string` and `std::wstring` data together, and doing so incorrectly.

`std::wstringstream` does not have an `operator<<` for `char*` input, so you are actually invoking its `operator<<` for `void*` input instead.  That operator formats the value of the pointer itself, not the data that it is pointing at.  So you end up passing bad input to `ToolUpdater.exe`.

You would have caught this error at compile time if you were not using `c_str()` so much.  Don't use `c_str()` unless you really need a raw character pointer (like in the `ShellExecute()` parameters).  If you avoid raw pointers, the compiler can perform better type-safe validations for you:

```
std::string szArg = " -i " + m_strSign;
std::wstringstream wss;
wss << szArg; // ERROR!
std::wstringstream wssa;
wssa << strToolupdater; // ERROR!
ShellExecute(NULL, TEXT("open"), wssa.str().c_str(), wss.str().c_str(), TEXT(""), SW_NORMAL);
std::wcout << wssa.str() << wss.str() << std::endl;
```

That being said, you really don't need the `std::wstringstream` objects in this example, you can remove them completely.

If you call `ShellExecuteA()` instead, you can pass your `std::string` values to it like this:

```
std::string szArg = "-i " + m_strSign;
ShellExecuteA(NULL, "open", strToolupdater.c_str(), szArg.c_str(), NULL, SW_NORMAL);
std::cout << strToolupdater << " " << szArg << std::endl;
```

Or, if you change everything to `std::wstring`:

```
std::wstring szArg = L"-i " + m_strSign;
ShellExecuteW(NULL, L"open", strToolupdater.c_str(), szArg.c_str(), NULL, SW_NORMAL);
std::wcout << strToolupdater << L" " << szArg << std::endl;
```

If you cannot change your `m_strSign` and `strToolupdater` variables themselves to `std::wstring` (because other code still expects `std::string`), you can convert them to `std::wstring` temporarily when needed:

```
std::wstring toWStr(const std::string &s)
{
    std::wstring ret;
    int len = MultiByteToWideChar(0, 0, s.c_str(), s.length(), NULL, 0);
    if (len > 0)
    {
        ret.resize(len);
        MultiByteToWideChar(0, 0, s.c_str(), s.length(), &ret[0], len);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

```
std::wstring szToolUpdater = toWStr(strToolupdater);
std::wstring szArg = L"-i " + toWStr(m_strSign);
ShellExecuteW(NULL, L"open", szToolUpdater.c_str(), szArg.c_str(), NULL, SW_NORMAL);
std::wcout << szToolUpdater << L" " << szArg << std::endl;
```